# How to filter on date in Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out how to properly filter on dates in big query. For instance in MS sql I do:

```
Select a, b, date from table_1 where date >= '2017-05-01'
```

In big query the filter doesn't work and it returns all the records. I tried

```
Select a, b, date from table_1 where date >= Date("2017-05-01")
Select a, b, date from table_1 where date >= 2017-05-01
Select a, b, date from table_1 where date >= timestamp('2017-05-01')
```

None of those worked. The documentation mentioned creating a partitioned table, but I'm not sure that is what I need to do ( and I hope not).

Please help :(

Comment: what data type your `date` field? is it `date` or `string`?

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant The column date is a datetype

Comment: you might want to show an example of your data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The column date is a datetype

Try below example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, DATE '2017-04-20' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2017-05-20' 
)
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE date > '2017-05-01'
```

the output is

```sql
a   b   date     
1   2   2017-05-20
```

Comment: example above is FOR BigQuery Standard SQL- just run it as is in Web UI!!! I recommend you to present example of your data - so we will be able to help you!.

Comment: make sure `#standardSQL` is a part of a query, as it is in example!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your `date` is actually a string. To use it in date comparisons, you can first parse it as a date. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, b, date
FROM table_1
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) >= '2017-05-01';
```

You can try the query with some sample data:

```
#standardSQL
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 'foo' AS b, '20170501' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bar', '20170101' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'baz', '20170625'
)
SELECT a, b, date
FROM table_1
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) >= '2017-05-01';
```

Comment: I checked the type and it definitely says date. I  used the example above, but unfortunately bigQuery doesn't recognise the function parse_date:

    2.61 - 2.92: Unrecognized function parse_date

Comment: You didn't include the `#standardSQL` in the query that you ran. This is necessary to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead of legacy SQL.

Answer (score 1):

you can properly filter on dates in BigQuery --

```
SELECT a, b, date
FROM table_1
WHERE DATE(date) >= DATE('2017-05-01');
```

Try another way ->

```
SELECT a, b, date
FROM table_1
WHERE TIMESTAMP(date) >= TIMESTAMP('2017-05-01');
```

To ensure that these methods operate properly, make sure that the date column in your table_1 is of a suitable date or timestamp data type. The date format ('2017-05-01') given is compliant with BigQuery's normal date format.